# Angular creating a Modal with google maps in iframe

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material

I am trying to create a modal in my angular app that when open show google maps in an iframe.

My issue is that the iframe doesent load and I get this error in browser console:

> chromewebdata/:1 Refused to display 'https://www.google.com/' in a
> frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'.

Here is the code of my modal:

```
<h2 mat-dialog-title>Google maps</h2>
<mat-dialog-content class="mat-typography">
  <iframe [src]="'https://maps.google.com/?q={{customer.address}},{{customer.city}}' | safe" width="800" height="600" style="border:0;" allowfullscreen="" loading="lazy" referrerpolicy="no-referrer-when-downgrade"></iframe>
</mat-dialog-content>
<mat-dialog-actions align="end">
  <button mat-button mat-dialog-close>Zapri</button>
</mat-dialog-actions>
```

the customer address and city is data i get from an API and the " | safe" is a url sanitizer pipe... My idea was to put together a url like this:
[https://maps.google.com/?q=1200 Pennsylvania Ave SE, Washington, District of Columbia, 20003](https://maps.google.com/?q=1200%20Pennsylvania%20Ave%20SE,%20Washington,%20District%20of%20Columbia,%2020003)

Is this even a correct approach? Should I do something differently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `X-Frame-Options` header on Google Maps page disallows using Google Maps inside of iframe. That's what the error says.

If you want to display google maps in your application, you need to do so using Google Maps javascript API.

There is a [google-map component](https://github.com/angular/components/tree/main/src/google-maps#readme) from the Angular team to help you with that.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to click the Share button [image: icon screenshot] on the maps homepage, switch to the "embed" tab and copy the template for the embedding in an iframe from there. It even contains the `<iframe>` tag so I think this is designed for it.